# Tomcat java servlet redirecting to wrong URL

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, redirect, metadata

I have a login servlet that is supposed to send a redirect to a specified url but instead I seem to be getting sent to an older version. I am using Tomcat 7 in eclipse and thinking it must be somewhere in the meta data that is screwie.

```
response.sendRedirect("../xyz/home.jsp");
```

but instead of going to xyz/home.jsp I am going to xyz1/home.jsp.

I had an old project called xyz1 which I then did a refracter to change the name to xyz. Now it seems that the login servlet keeps referring to xyz1/home.jsp. My other links are fine since I am using href and relative paths. I did a search through the meta-data to see if there was any older references to xyz1 and there were so I changed them and I also did a search in the server configuration files which I had also fixed. Not sure what other options there are. 
Thanks,
-Tommy

Also the debugger is kind of useless since it goes through .class files that cant be read ...

Comment: some leftovers may exist in your project from the previous one. Try searching for string `xyz1.jsp`. I am sure you will hit something

Comment: I tried that. ctr+h in eclipse to go through the file-system. I got as much of that as possible. Still seems to be re-routing to the wrong URL

Comment: Please stick to absolute URIs when sending a redirect.

Comment: I don't see the relevance to whether I use absolute vs relative paths in this case. I could put in response.sendRedirect("BLAHBLAH"); and it still would go to xyz1/home.jsp

Comment: Well I fixed it. I didn't want to do it this way because I would have liked to learn what went wrong, but it worked. I renamed xyz to be xyz1 and then just made a blank project called xyz. Only moved my source files and let the metadata fill in itself. I also made a new server just to be safe.

Comment: @Gene Parmesan in SO remember that you can answer your own questions. So, feel free to do it and accept it, so we can limit the number of unanswered questions

Comment: I wasn't allowed to until after 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed xyz to be xyz1 and then just made a blank project called xyz. Only moved my source files and let the metadata fill in itself. I also made a new server just to be safe.

Comment: Next time, try clearing Tomcat's work directory. In Eclipse: right click on the server (in the Servers view) and choose Clean Tomcat Work Directory.